# Samsung GT P1000: Install to internal storage?

Tags: installation, samsung-galaxy-tab, internal-sd

Is it possible to install apps on the internal USB (`/mnt/sdcard`) storage of the Samsung GT P1000?

`/mnt/sdcard` has 7Gb free and the internal phone storage only 690Mb free.

Move 2 SD card fails with `"Failed to move application. No SD card."`

Surely there must be a way to install apps on the internal storage.

Comment: By "internal usb" do you mean internal SD card? Are you trying to move apps to internal SD card or external? If external, do you have an (external) SD card inserted in your device?

Comment: My GT-P1000 has 16GB internal (dynamic) storage. In other words, although it has a microSD slot, regardless of any microSD card being inserted, there is always a 16GB partition available under /mnt/sdcard I tried force2sd, but although my P1000 is rooted, the app fails each time with "Operation unsuccessful!"

Answer (score 1):

You can move apps that support it to that SD Card, as that is the one used by Android to install apps to.

Just go to settings apps and select the app, and then click the move to SD Card button.

If you want to move them ALL you must be rooted, and can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.pruss.force2sd_lite), which allows you to force apps to the (internal) SD Card.